# Kendo DropdownList not selecting bind values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I have A kendo DropdownList like as below. When my page is loading, I load two times of my Kendo DDL with different value. What I need is I want to bind only last time loaded value into my Kendo DDL and select a first value. My Kendo DDL bind with correct values but it does not select a first value from last loaded value.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.SemesterID)
.HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true", style = "width:320px" })
.OptionLabel("Select Semester Below...")
.Name("SemesterID") 
.DataTextField("SemesterName") 
.DataValueField("SemesterID") 
.AutoBind(true)                 
        .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetSemester", "StudentRSRegistration").Data("loadSemester"); 

            })
            .ServerFiltering(true); client.
        })
.SelectedIndex(0)
```

)

This is my method for get values for DDL

```
public List<StudentRSRegistartionModel> GetSemester(int? ProgrammeID1, int? SpecializationID1, int? SpecializationLevelID1, int? IntakeID1, int? IntakeYear )
    {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProgrammeID1.ToString()) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(SpecializationID1.ToString()))
                {
                    obj = (from tbsr in context.tblSemesterRegistrations
                           join tbintake in context.tblIntakes on tbsr.IntakeID equals tbintake.intakeID
                           where
                           ((tbsr.ProgrammeID == ProgrammeID1) &&
                           ((tbsr.SpecializationID == null)) &&
                           (tbsr.IntakeID == IntakeID1 || !(tbsr.IntakeID.HasValue)) &&
                           (tbsr.IntakeYear == IntakeYear || !(tbsr.AcadamiYear.HasValue)))

                           select new StudentRSRegistartionModel
                           {
                               SemesterID = tbsr.SemesterID,
                               intakeYear = tbsr.IntakeYear,
                               AcadamicSemester = tbsr.AcadamicSemester,
                               Acadamicyear = tbsr.AcadamiYear,
                               IntakeCode = tbintake.IntakeCode,
                               SpecializationID = tbsr.SpecializationID,

                           }).OrderByDescending(o => o.SemesterID).ToList()

                                                           .Select(tb => new StudentRSRegistartionModel()
                                                           {
                                                               intakeYear = tb.intakeYear,
                                                               SemesterID = tb.SemesterID,
                                                               IntakeCode = tb.IntakeCode,
                                                               SemesterName = "Year " + tb.Acadamicyear + ": Semester " + tb.AcadamicSemester + ": Intake " + tb.IntakeCode,
                                                           }).OrderBy(o => o.SemesterName).ToList();

                }




                return obj;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

[image: my DDL is now like this, But I want to select first value]

this method gives me correct values in both time. Could any one have a idea why this Kendo DDL is not selecting correctly....Thnaks....

Comment: Can you clarify what "last time loaded value" means.

Comment: What is that "loadSemester" function in `read.Action("GetSemester", "StudentRSRegistration").Data("loadSemester");`? What does it do?

Comment: loadSemester passing the parameters..It's working perfect...

Comment: in my case when page is loading, I use cascade event to fire Kendo DDL.  last time load values means, When the last cascade event is fire it will load the values. it loads two time the Kendo DDL. I want to show only last time values. In here it's load correctly, but it not select the first value.